# How to get a file object from mongodb using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am currently using:

```
some_fs = gridfs.GridFS(db, "some.col")
fs_file = some_fs.get(index)
```

to get a `<class 'gridfs.grid_file.GridOut'>` object.

**How do I get a file object instead or how do I convert this to a python file object?**
Do I have to save as a temp file to do this?

Edit:

This is the full code I am using:

```
FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg.exe"
some_fs = gridfs.GridFS(db, "some.col")
vid_id = ObjectId("5339e3b5b322631b544b2338")

vid_file = some_fs.get(vid_id)
raw =  vid_file.read()
print type(vid_file), type(raw)

with open(raw, "rb") as infile:
    pipe = sp.Popen([FFMPEG_BIN,
                 # "-v", "quiet",
                 "-y",
                 "-i", "-",
                 "-vcodec", "copy", "-acodec", "copy",
                 "-ss", "00:00:00", "-t", "00:00:10", "-sn",
                 "test.mp4" ]
                ,stdin=infile, stdout=sp.PIPE
)
pipe.wait()
```

Output:

```
[2014-03-31 19:03:00] Connected to DB.
<class 'gridfs.grid_file.GridOut'> <type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/proj/src/lib/ffmpeg/win/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open(raw, "rb") as infile:
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Maybe the `GridOut` isn't a proper implementation of python [file objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects).  My last suggestion is to try using a memory file with [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html).

```
import StringIO

FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg.exe"
some_fs = gridfs.GridFS(db, "some.col")
vid_id = ObjectId("5339e3b5b322631b544b2338")

vid_file = some_fs.get(vid_id)

# Should be a proper file-like object
infile =  StringIO.StringIO(vid_file.read())

pipe = sp.Popen([FFMPEG_BIN,
    # "-v", "quiet",
    "-y",
    "-i", "-",
    "-vcodec", "copy", "-acodec", "copy",
    "-ss", "00:00:00", "-t", "00:00:10", "-sn",
    "test.mp4" ]
    ,stdin=infile, stdout=sp.PIPE
)
pipe.wait()

...

infile.close()
```

Comment: infile is not set to anything... what should I use as input?

Comment: That gives me: `TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not GridOut`

Comment: @Jeff, it looks like `GridOut` isn't a proper implementation of python file-like objects.  Try creating a memory file to read from.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: That gives:  

File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 665, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 772, in _get_handles
    p2cread = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(stdin.fileno())
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'fileno'

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/gridfs.html) you need to use .read() method.

I think that `some_fs.get(index).read()` will give you what you need.

Comment: @Jeff can you please tell what kind of string is there and what do you expect to be in a file? It sounds like your `<class ...>` is actually a fileobject and read() gives you what is inside of that file.

Comment: I edited my question... I hope this doesn't change my question too much!

Answer (score 0):

> This worked for me

```
FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg.exe"
some_fs = gridfs.GridFS(db, "some.col")
vid_id = ObjectId("5339e3b5b322631b544b2338")

vid_file = some_fs.get(vid_id)

pipe = sp.Popen([FFMPEG_BIN,
    # "-v", "quiet",
    "-y",
    "-i", "-",
    "-vcodec", "copy", "-acodec", "copy",
    "-ss", "00:00:00", "-t", "00:00:10", "-sn",
    "test.mp4" ]
    ,stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE
)
pipe.stdin=vid_file.read()
```